# How to change a file name containing ":" in timing info

Tags: linux, filenames, timestamps

I am learning Linux commands.

When rename the file name with timing info, there are `:` marks automatically assigned. how can I change this `:` sign to `_`?

Below is a file name example. It was updated with timing info. how to name it by replacing `:` with `_`?

```
ee_Sun_Aug_11_22:20:27_GMT-8_2019.txt
```

Also, why below did not work?

```
$ cp /var/log/ee.txt ee_`date`.txt
cp: target `2019.txt' is not a directory
```

Answer (score 6):

To loop over all files in the current directory that contain at least one `:` character in their name and ends with `.txt`, and to change the `:` characters to `_`, with the ksh93, zsh, bash, mksh shells (or recent versions of busybox sh), you may use

```bash
for name in ./*:*.txt; do
    newname=${name//:/_}
    mv -i "$name" "$newname"
done
```

or, shorter,

```bash
for name in ./*:*.txt; do
    mv -i "$name" "${name//:/_}"
done
```

The parameter substitution `${name//:/_}` would change all `:` to `_` anywhere in the value `$name` (a ksh93 operator also supported by the shells mentioned above).

The `mv -i` would rename the file, but would ask for confirmation if the new name is already taken.

The filename that you show as an example would be changed to `ee_Sun_Aug_11_22_20_27_GMT-8_2019.txt`.

---

Your command

```
cp /var/log/ee.txt ee_`date`.txt
```

does not work because `date` outputs a string with spaces in it.  The spaces would have made `cp` think you wanted to copy *several* files into a directory. Hence the "is not a directory" error.

The following would have worked better:

```
cp /var/log/ee.txt "ee_$(date).txt"
```

It works better, not because I changed your backticks to `$(...)` but because I double-quoted the new name.

This would have created the file `ee_Sun Aug 11 16:57:37 CEST 2019.txt` (or something similar).

To get a neater looking filename, you may want to specify the output format for `date` a bit more precisely:

```
cp ee.txt "ee_$(date +"%F_%H-%M-%S").txt"
```

The format string `%F_%H-%M-%S` would be described in the `strftime(3)` manual on your system (`man 3 strftime`), or in the manual for the `date` command, and you would end up with a filename like `ee_2019-08-11_16-59-55.txt`. If your `date` doesn't support the `%F` directive, you can replace with `%Y-%m-%d`.

Alternatively,

```
cp ee.txt "$(date +"ee_%F_%H-%M-%S.txt")"
```

(letting the `date` command format do most of the work in creating the new filename)

Comment: Thank you very much for advice above. Now my commands work